# Multiple datatables under different tabs, one with Ajax source

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have 2 tables under 2 tabs. The table under default tab shows the datatables fine. The second table is populated from Ajax source (JSON array). Problem is I am not able to initialize this table with DataTables.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        if(activeTab == "#tab2"){   
        $.getJSON("<url>",              
            function(data) {
                    htmlTable = '<table id="table2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">'; 
                                    htmlTable+=<data...>;
                    htmlTable +='</tbody></table>';
                        $('#table2').remove();
                        $('#tab2').append(htmlTable);
            });

        }

               $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

});
```

If I explicitly initialize in the success function of the getJSON() call, I see multiple such DataTables on every click of the tab. How to initialize this dataTable...

Comment: I fixed this by explicity initializing dataTables **after checking if one is present and removing it**: 'if ($("#table2_wrapper").length > 0){
        $('#table2_wrapper').remove();
       }'

Answer (score 2):

I have some questions.Why are you using `$,getJSON()` when d`ataTables` has inbuilt functionality for that? Why are you creating the table dynamically `onclick` of the tab?IF you want to load the table content only on clicking of second tab then make a static table and put the dataTables initialization code inside the onclick tab2 code

**HTML**

```
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
  <table class="display dataTable" id="table2">
    <thead>
      <tr>col1</tr>
       ....
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
        if(activeTab == "#tab2"){          
           oTable2 = $('#table2').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "yourURL"
        }
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });
```

I still think you should load the second table on page load not on clicking of second tab if the size of the content is not too large

Comment: Your suggestion gave me error. The table is populated with JSON array via getJSON.

Comment: that's what i m saying ,if you are using ajax and json then why are you using `getJSON` method why don't you use the `ajaxSource` feature provided by the dataTable plugin for this very purpose